# Wsl2 why develop in this environment

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote, wsl-2

I understand the principal of having Linux on your windows box over using a VM.

I have seen articles on using vscode in wsl with the vscode wsl extension.

My question is why would I do this over just using vscode on Windows.

Might sound like a silly question and I hear people saying I can now develop on Linux where my company is is windows, I just don't understand what the benefits are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what you are developing, if its C# with the target operating system being windows or azure there is little benefit.

Personally I work in nodejs, our target deployment OS is centos running in AWS-EC2, so it makes total sense. There is a lot of tooling that runs better in a linux environment than in a dos/powershell environment. Also when testing we are running the code in an environment that is close to our target env which reduces the chances of unforeseen issues further.

Does this make sense? what are you developing day to day and what is your target environment?

Comment: Thanks @Damo, more tooling is the answer as u said. Using terraform and a lot of tooling is Linux based